# Linkedin API standardized data endpoints permissions

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch the different standardized data to make a custom post targeting form.

So I'm accessing the different endpoints mentioned at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/standardized-data

When using a client_credentials token (app token) I get "Not enough permissions to access ****".

When using an user token I can access without a problem.

The question is why do I need an user token to get this data that is global and, according to its definition, used to standardize data across the LinkedIn platform

Comment: Can you please tell how did you get acccess to v2? I'm getting a 403 error on all v2 endpoints either with clien_credentials or with user token. And we are a lready a partner in the linkedin api developer program.

Comment: I applied here: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Answer (score 1):

"Not enough permissions to access" when it looks like your permissions SHOULD work, usually means you need to be a LinkedIn "Partner":

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Comment: It's not the case. Access to v2 was already approved. Using an user token I'm able to get the data, but why an user token is needed while an app token should be enough

Comment: @HugoSarti by the app token you mean the code generate? and user token you mean access token?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish no, with app token I mean the token you get when using client_credentials. It should be used when accessing endpoints that don't involve user context.